# Problem using toggle() on hidden DIVs with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, hide

> **EDIT:** the problem was not on hiding them (as I first thought), It was
>   on using the function toggle() on the hidden DIVs , so I changed the Title Question in
>   hope it helps someone with similar problem

I have problems to hide/show DIVs using the toggle() function:

**the code I am using:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
<style type="text/css">
div{width:200px;padding:5px;padding-left:30px;border:0 solid #000;border-left-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;font-weight:700}
p{color:grey}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main span").click(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).parent().attr("id") + " div").toggle("fast");
    });

    $("#main div").hide();

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <span>hider</span>
    <div id="main-child1"><p>content-child1</p></div>
    <div id="main-child2">
        <span>hider</span>
        <div id="ultra-child"><p>content-ultrachild</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-child3"><p>content-child3</p></div>
    <div id="main-child4">
        <span>hider</span>
        <div id="child-child4"><p>content-c4</p></div>

        <div id="main-child5">
            <span>hider</span>
            <div id="child-c5"><p>content-chl5</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the problem? it seems to be quite working for me.

Comment: Seems to be working for me in Firefox, and I see nothing wrong with any of your attempts. What browser are you using?

Comment: To <Rikudo Sennin> and <Saad Imran>: The problem was not entirely on hiding them, but afterwards when using the toggle() on the hidden Divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are selecting (and therefore showing) ALL divs when you click on a `hider`.  Use the child selector to only open the levels you want:

```
$("#" + $(this).parent().attr("id") + " > div").toggle("fast");
```

However, a better solution would be to just toggle the siblings of the `hider`

```
$(this).siblings("div").toggle("fast");
```

Your code to hide the elements works fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EppSm/6

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('#main>div').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

1. `$(function() {})` will make your script start as soon as the page is ready.
2. `$('#main>div')` Target all the first level div in #main.
3. fadeOut make fade the selected Div.

Answer (score 1):

Add a trigger for the first element:

`$("#main span:first").trigger("click");`

http://jsfiddle.net/EppSm/4/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$("#main > div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$("#main").find("div").hide();
```

Comment: Would be more efficient if you combine $("#main").find("div") into $('#main>div')

Comment: Note that `.find` does not do the same thing as `>`. `$('#main').find('div')` is equal to `$('#main div')`.

Comment: @Simon: hmmm..maybe you're right. But the question says "hiding ALL divs" and first thought was `.find()` (.find() finds all elements no matter their dom level ..not only first level).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using `toggle()` on an element which is inside a hidden DIV, this is a known bug. It is not fixed as far as I can tell (using jquery 1.7.2) according to the [documentation](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4681).